# Why the first 2 querys don't return anything?

Tags: mysql

For some reason the first two query's don't show anything. I made it so, that you press a submit button to post your input, and then have it controlled and added to the database. But it doesn't work.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM rubrieklink WHERE rekeningnummer = '".$_POST["rekeningnummer"]."'";
$resultrubrieken = $mysqli->query($sql);
$sql="INSERT INTO betalingen(
    bedrijf
    ,rekeningnummer
    ,prijs
    ,rubriek) 
    VALUES('".$_POST["name"]."'
    ,'".$_POST["rekeningnummer"]."'
    ,".$_POST["prijs"]."
    ,'".$resultrubrieken["rubriek"]."')";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$resultbetalingen = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM betalingen");
if ($resultbetalingen->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<center><table><tr><td>bedrijf</td><td>rekeningnummer</td><td>prijs</td><td>rubriek</td></tr>";
    while($betalingen = $resultbetalingen->fetch_assoc()){
        echo"<tr><td>".$betalingen['bedrijf']."</td><td>".$betalingen['rekeningnummer']."</td><td>".$betalingen['prijs']."</td><td>".$betalingen['rubriek']."</td></tr>";
    }
    echo"</table>";

}
```

Comment: Do the same queries produce the results you want when entered directly into your sql client?

Comment: Do you have error reporting turned on? Add this to the top of your file: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);`

Comment: i tried putting it at the top of my file.
and when i put it directly in my sql client i do get the results i need.

Comment: Your insert  uses a wrong syntax.Maybe show the connection also.

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362/my-question-was-downvoted-closed-because-it-was-full-of-grammatical-mistakes-wh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is rekeningnummer an INTEGER or a string if so you must quote your strings same goes for the insert for example $_POST["name"] is not quoted
PS also why is the INSERT INTO doubled in your query?

Comment: thank you i tried to edit my insert into to my newest version but did it wrong